# how many steps are required for the pattern 0; 0; 1 to first appear

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Can anyone help me with this?

A sequence of 0’s and 1’s is generated by a Markov chain with transition matrix

P=    \begin{pmatrix}
    1/4 & 3/4 \\
    3/4 & 1/4  \\
    \end{pmatrix}

and the first element of the sequence is decided by a fair coin toss. On average, how many steps are
required for the pattern 0; 0; 1 to first appear?

I am thinking of using conditional expectation but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_{00}$ be the expected number of additional steps needed to reach $0, 0, 1$ if the last two steps were $0,0$, let $E_0$ be the expected number of additional steps needed to reach $0, 0, 1$ if the last step was $0$, but the last two were not $0, 0$. And let $E_1$ be the expected number of additional steps needed to reach $0, 0, 1$ if the last step was not a $0$.

Then we have, by conditional expectation, that
$$
E_{00} = \frac34\cdot 1 + \frac14(1 + E_{00})\\
E_{0} = \frac34(1 + E_1) + \frac14(1+E_{00})\\
E_1 = \frac14(1+E_1) + \frac34(1+E_0)
$$
They give the result
$$
E_{00} = \frac43\\
E_{0} = \frac{28}3\\
E_1 = \frac{32}3
$$
And, since you use a coin toss to decide whether you start at $E_0$ or at $E_1$, the total expected number of steps is therefore
$$
\frac{\frac{28}3 + \frac{32}3}{2} = 10
$$